# GeoListPlot and interfering colors?

Tags: plotting

Exploring Wolfram Language databases.
First:

```
EntityClass[
  "City", {"Country" -> Entity["Country", "Netherlands"], 
   "Population" -> 
    GreaterThan[Quantity[500000, "People"]]}] // EntityList
```

I get 3 cities: Amsterdam, Rotterdam, The Hague

But Rotterdam is lacking as a red dot when I do:

```
GeoListPlot[  
 EntityClass[
  "City", {"Country" -> Entity["Country", "Netherlands"], 
   "Population" -> GreaterThan[Quantity[500000, "People"]]}]]
```

Is it just a matter of interfering colors?

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Adding `PlotMarkers -> Point` fixes it.

Comment: The reason that there's no dot for Rotterdam is that it has a polygon that displays as a region on the map. The other two cities don't have polygons. See: `EntityClass["City", {"Country" -> Entity["Country", "Netherlands"], "Population" -> GreaterThan[Quantity[500000, "People"]]}]~EntityValue~"HasPolygon"`